# LINQ to Entities and casting

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-5

I have a few EF code first classes that has a CategoryId member, which is also definied in the interface called ICategoryFilterable.

```
    public class One : ICategoryFilterable
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        /* more properties here */
    }

    public class Two : ICategoryFilterable
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        /* more properties here */
    }

    public interface ICategoryFilterable
    {
        int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I'd like to retrieve the records from the database by the specified categories. I've created a generic method for this, but it is not working and I can't find the solution to do this.

```
    private IQueryable<T> FilterByCategory<T>(IQueryable<T> items, IEnumerable<int> filter)
        where T : ICategoryFilterable
    {
        return from item in items
               where filter.Contains(item.CategoryId)
               select item;
    }
```

> Unable to cast the type 'MyNamespace.One' to type 'MyNamespace.ICategoryFilterable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work...

You could use a delegate to select the appropriate category ID:

```
    private IQueryable<T> FilterByCategory<T>
                (IQueryable<T> items, IEnumerable<int> filter, 
                 Func<T, int> categorySelector)
    {
        return items.Where(i => filter.Contains(categorySelector(i)));
    }
```

Quick usage example:

```
        var source = Enumerable.Empty<One>().AsQueryable();
        var filter = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

        var filtered = FilterByCategory(source, filter, s => s.CategoryId);
```

Comment: Please see my changes. However, this won't work either(read the exception).

Comment: Could you add an example of your FilterByCategory method call to your question?

Comment: The IEnumerable<F> is just a list of integers. This is NOT the problem. It can't cast the `One` to `ICategoryFilterable` to get the proper records from the database.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is not possible without enumerating the source to memory beforehand.  I have edited my answer to provide an alternative solution.